# If $E[f(X,U)|X]=0$, does $H[f(X,U)]<H[f(X,U)+g(X)]$?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, inequality

Suppose everything is continuous and smooth, $X,U$ are independent, $H[f(X,U)|X]>0, E[f(X,U)|X]=0$. Then for $g$ s.t. $H[g(X)]>0$, does
 $$H[f(X,U)]<H[f(X,U)+g(X)]$$
hold?

I did some quick experiments and it seems so, but is there a proof?

Comment: Are you saying $X,U$ are conditionally independent? If yes, with respect to what?

Comment: @AlexR. I meant they are unconditionally independent.

Comment: Could you rewrite the question to be fully contained in the body? It's confusing whether the statements about $H$ being positive are assumptions, or whether that's what you're trying to rpove.

Comment: @AlexR. Sorry. Is it clear now?